# How to match a string in this way?

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if a String matches this specific pattern.

The pattern is:

> (Numbers)(all characters allowed)(numbers)

and the numbers may have a comma ("." or ",")!

For instance the input could be `500+400` or `400,021+213.443`.

I tried `Pattern.matches("[0-9],?.?+[0-9],?.?+", theequation2)`, but it didn't work!

I know that I have to use the method Pattern.match(regex, String), but I am not being able to find the correct regex.

Comment: please, give possible input and output, and show your attempt.

Comment: Done! I have added them"

Comment: If "all characters are allowed", then there is no way to know the start of the 2nd numbers group (as numbers are a subset of "all"). So there must be a better differentiation here.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: Your requirement is too vague. You might as well use `s.matches("\\d.*\\d")` to match a string starting and ending with a digit and having any 0+ chars in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with numbers can be difficult. This approach will deal with your examples, but check carefully. I also didn't do "all characters" in the middle grouping, as "all" would include numbers, so instead I assumed that finding the next non-number would be appropriate.

This Java regex handles the requirements:

```
"((-?)[\\d,.]+)([^\\d-]+)((-?)[\\d,.]+)"
```

However, there is a potential issue in the above. Consider the following:
`300 - -200`. The foregoing won't match that case.

Now, based upon the examples, I think the point is that one should have a valid operator. The number of math operations is likely limited, so I would whitelist the operators in the middle. Thus, something like:

```
"((-?)[\\d,.]+)([\\s]*[*/+-]+[\\s]*)((-?)[\\d,.]+)"
```

Would, I think, be more appropriate. The `[*/+-]` can be expanded for the power operator `^` or whatever. Now, if one is going to start adding words (such as `mod`) in the equation, then the expression will need to be modified.

You can see [this regular expression here](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyywb6wyr)

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you have to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally and escape the `\+` or else it would make the `?` a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). To match 1+ digits you have to use a quantifier `[0-9]+`

For your example data, you could match 1+ digits followed by an optional part which matches either a dot or a comma at the start and at the end. If you want to match 1 time any character you could use a dot.

Instead of using a dot, you could also use for example a character class `[-+*]` to list some operators or list what you would allow to match. If this should be the only match, you could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

```
\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?.\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?.\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9X3GUt/1)

That would match:

- `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?` 1+ digits followed by an optional part that matches `.` or `,` followed by 1+ digits
- `.` Match any character (Use .`+`) to repeat 1+ times
- Same as the first pattern